# Laravel auth user not working in welcome page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am new with laravel. And i got this issue.
I have this routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PublicController@index');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','admin']], function ($username) {
    Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\AdminController@index');
    Route::controller('/admin/user', 'Admin\UserController');
});
```

In admin page, it shows my login and register button replaced by the user name. But when i go to public page / the user name disappear and showing login and register button instead. Its not get logged out yet, if i back to admin page, i still logged in.

Can someone help me out with explanation, what happended and what should i do??
thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Try put `Route::get('/', 'PublicController@index');` into `Route::group(...);`

`['middleware' => ['web']]` will log your account.

Comment: lol, yea its work.. i though ['middleware' => ['web']] will force users to the login page. What this middleware do exactly?

Comment: Your can see `'middleware' => ['web']]` call classes in `\App\Http\Kernel.php`.

Comment: You also add some classes to check something in this, for me: `[
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LoginSuccess::class,
        ]`

Comment: So there is no authentication class in middlewar web..
I got confused, because when i delete Route::auth(); in the Route::group(...); and then i logged out, i cant acces public page.

Comment: I dont use `Route::auth();`, I check `auth()` by `if (auth()->check()) {
            return view('success.index')->with($this->_getDataActivity());
        } else {

            return view('register.index')->with($this->_getDataRegister());
        }`

Comment: With `middleware ` : `if (auth()->check()) {return $next($request);
        }
        else {return redirect('/')} `